# Need a package to compute constraint structure

Tags: packages, constraint, field-theory

I want to compute constraint structure of some field theory and some gravitational field theory. By constraint structure I mean what is explained in the "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by P. A. M. Dirac.

Now, I have some questions:

1 - Is there any package in this way? or any algorithm for computing constraint structure of theories?

2-I am trying to find constraint structure of electromagnetic theory as an example using xAct package but I could not compute time derivatives of fields to construct momenta and Hamiltonian. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It is quite unclear to me what you might mean with "constraint structure"...

Comment: I think he's talking about constraints arising from passing from the Lagrangian to the Hamiltonian due to non-invertibility of relations connecting the velocities to the canonical momenta.

Comment: @QuantumDot I mean exactly constraint structure of singular Lagrangians as explained in the "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by Dirac. 
  [link]{https://books.google.com/books?id=Z3XCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Dirac&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie6I-f4bfeAhUIaFAKHUurDSsQ6AEILzAC}

Answer (score 3):

About your first question, I don't know any package  in mathematica, but there are some algorithms among who do applied mathematics based on Groebner basis. I know one of these algorithms written in Maple.

2- as you talked about xAct, maybe xTras be useful for you. Also you can ask your question on xAct google group. It seems that active people in this community are not familiar with constraint structure and judge your question ...